# lstlisting with sublistings and captions and floating environment

Tags: listings, subfloats

I try to create a floating environment with a layout similar to this:

```
_____________________  ___________________
|                    | |                 |
|                    | |                 |
|                    | |                 |
_____________________  ___________________
(a) First sublisting   (c) Third sublisting

__________________________________________
|                                        |
|                                        |
|                                        |
__________________________________________
             (b) Second sublisting

Listing 3.1: Main caption for all sublistings
```

I use `\usepackage{subcaption}` and `\usepackage{lstlisting}`

My current approach is that I put the three listings in subfigures inside a figure. Afterwards I use several tricks:

1. In the figure I use `\captionof{lstlisting}{Main caption for all sublistings}` to explicitly use a listing caption instead a caption for a figure
2. Although I use `\captionof{lstlisting}{...}`, the counter for figures is increased. Thus I manually decrease it after the figure environment via `\addtocounter{figure}{-1}`.
3. Although I use `\captionof{lstlisting}{...}`, an `\autoref{}` to this figure prints "Figure 3.1" instead "Listing 3.1". Thus I have to reference it via `Listing \ref{...}`

With this approach the listings are laid out correct, have subcaptions and a main caption and are in a floating environment. They appear in the correct list (list of figures vs. list of listings) and references use the correct naming.

My question is: Is there an easier way of doing this?
Manually modifying the index of figures and using `\ref` instead `\autoref`
just feels kind of wrong.

Is it possible to tell the figure environment to increase its counter only 
if its caption is actually a caption for figures?
Is it possible to modify `\autoref` to use the correct reference when `\captionof{lstlisting}{...}` in a figure is used?

### Example

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

This is a reference to Listing~\ref{lst:mylisting}.
In contrast to this, autoref prints \autoref{lst:mylisting}.

\begin{figure}[tb]
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.45\textwidth}
        \renewcommand{\thesubfigure}{a}
        \begin{lstlisting}
bla bla
        \end{lstlisting}
        \caption{First listing}
    \end{subfigure}
    \hfill
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.45\textwidth}
        \renewcommand{\thesubfigure}{c}
        \begin{lstlisting}
bla bla
        \end{lstlisting}
        \caption{Third listing}
    \end{subfigure}

    \vspace{10mm}

    \begin{subfigure}[t]{1\textwidth}
        \renewcommand{\thesubfigure}{b}
        \begin{lstlisting}
bla bla
        \end{lstlisting}
        \caption{Second listing}
    \end{subfigure}
    \captionof{lstlisting}{Main caption for all sublistings}
    \label{lst:mylisting}
\end{figure}
% modify numbering of figures
\addtocounter{figure}{-1}

\begin{figure}[tb]
    \caption{A following figure with correct numbering}

    This is the figure content
\end{figure}

\listoffigures
\lstlistoflistings

\end{document}
```

Comment: If you use [`cleveref`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/cleveref), as in `\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}` and them `cref prints \cref{lst:mylisting}` you get the right name.

Comment: I got an additional issue: How can I reference the subfigures? Not only that they are referenced via `Figure x`, but they are also referenced with the index of the figure instead of the listing.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you set up a correct subcaption type, then you can use the `\subcaption` command directly.  In the "figure" containing listings, just declare use `\setcaptiontype` to `lstlisting` to get it in the correct sequence separate from figures.  With `cleveref` you can get correct references.

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}

\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\AtBeginDocument{\DeclareCaptionSubType{lstlisting}}
\crefname{sublstlisting}{listing}{listings}
\Crefname{sublstlisting}{Listing}{Listings}

\begin{document}

This is a reference to Listing~\ref{lst:mylisting}.
In contrast to this, cleveref prints \cref{lst:mylisting} and \cref{sublst:b}.

\begin{figure}[tb]
  \setcaptiontype{lstlisting}
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.45\textwidth}
        \begin{lstlisting}
bla bla
        \end{lstlisting}
        \subcaption{First listing}
        \label{sublst:a}
    \end{minipage}
    \hfill
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.45\textwidth}
      \begin{lstlisting}
bla bla
        \end{lstlisting}
        \subcaption{Second listing}
        \label{sublst:b}
    \end{minipage}

    \vspace{10mm}

    \begin{minipage}[t]{1\textwidth}
        \begin{lstlisting}
bla bla
        \end{lstlisting}
        \subcaption{Third listing}
        \label{sublst:c}
    \end{minipage}
    \caption{Main caption for all sublistings}
    \label{lst:mylisting}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[tb]
    \caption{A following figure with correct numbering}

    This is the figure content
\end{figure}

\listoffigures
\lstlistoflistings

\end{document}
```

Note the declaration of the subtype for listings has to be postponed to the beginning of the document, as that is when the corresponding float type is first definied.

I will let you play with the counter values to get your non-standard ordering of labels.